# Android game GLSurfaceView time handling

Tags: java, android, opengl-es-2.0

I am trying to make a small android game with Java and OpenGL ES 2.0.
Currently I am trying to create a good game loop for a smooth feeling if for example objects are moving.
I tried 4 approaches but all of them making me not happy.

Here my Approaches:

**Approach 1:**

```
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl)
{
    game.update(1.0f / 60.0f);
    game.render();
}
```

Result:

Approximately all 2 seconds there is a little lag/delay.
Between the 2 seconds it fells really smooth.

**Approach 2:**

```
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl)
{
        newTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        delTime = newTime - oldTime;
        oldTime = newTime;

        game.update(delTime / 1000.0f);
        game.render();
}
```

Result:

Approximately all 2 seconds there is a little lag/delay, exactly the same as "Approach 1".
Between the 2 seconds it fells really smooth.

**Approach 3:**

```
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl)
{
        newTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        delTime = newTime - oldTime;
        oldTime = newTime;
        lagTime += delTime;

        // 18ms ~ 55 Frames per second
        while(lagTime >= 18)
        {
            game.update(18 / 1000.0f);

            lagTime -= 18;
        }

        game.render();
}
```

Result:

Approximately all 0.5 seconds there is a little lag/delay.
It feels never smooth.

**Approach 4:**

```
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl)
{
    newTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    delTime = newTime - oldTime;
    oldTime = newTime;
    lagTime += delTime;

    // 18ms ~ 55 Frames per second
    while(lagTime >= 18)
    {
        game.update(18 / 1000.0f);

        lagTime -= 18;
    }

    // Render all linear interpolated dependent on the lag time.
    game.render(lagTime / 1000.0f);
}
```

Result:

Approximately all 2 seconds there is a little lag/delay, exactly the same as "Approach 1" and "Approach 2".
Between the 2 seconds it fells really smooth.

**Summary:**

I am pretty sure I am not allocating memory so the GC have not to work but what else could cause these lags all 2 seconds ?

And why the GLSurfaceView call the "onDrawFrame" method exactly 60 times per second without my to do(Sometimes 58 or 62 times per second, too) I thought it calls the method so often it can and 60 FPS sounds not randomly so is it possible to specify this rate and how this behave on other devices?

So finally whats a good simply approach without this lags all 2 seconds for a simple 2D game with fast moving objects(So 40-60 FPS should be the minimum) ?

If its important, I tested the approaches on the Nexus 7(2013) with Android 5.1.1.

Comment: FPS means frames per second(the times that the `onDrawFrame()` method get called in 1 second). You will never get a constant 60 FPS :3

Comment: I measured the function calls per second and I got 58 to 62 FPS as result.

Comment: 60 fps is the display refresh rate on most devices. Generally it makes sense to render a new frame for each display refresh, which is why the system calls `onDrawFrame()` 60 times per second.

Comment: Ok thanks. But what causes the lags every 2 seconds ?

Comment: Guess what make my code slow update(); render(); ?

Comment: Even if I just render only one triangle and make one calculation in the update method the 2 second lags are there. Its 100% not the bad of the two functions render() and update() the lags are there if a remove the two function calls, too.

Comment: Hard to tell what's causing those lags every 2 seconds. The first guess would normally be GC, but you seem confident that you're not allocating and releasing memory repeatedly. Could potentially be something else on the system that is consuming resources. In the delta times you are calculating, are they always at least 1/60 second, and sometimes significantly longer? Or do they just fluctuate, and still average 1/60 second?

Comment: The most time I get a delta time of 18 to 22 ms but sometimes(All 2 seconds) it drops to 10 ms or to 28.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after a few days trying to fix this problem I found another solution.
Now I am simply take a average delta time about 5 frames.
This seems to work better but not perfect.

Comment: Try to store 7 frames and drop 1 max and 1 min values

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to pass 18.f/1000.f into the function in the While statement?

It is not common to call update() in While loop in a game loop. 
Test it again without the code checking FPS and the while loop.

If nothing happened, I would sill doubt that something is allocating.

**UPDATE**

80ms with nothing to call, no way, the delta time is supposed to be less than 20ms . I think it is easy to find why. Try to run a official android sample which uses a opengl es view then if it happens again, no one knows what it is because of the device problem. However, I think it will works well then compare with a sample code in the GLSurfaceview with the main activity or you can show me your whole code in GLSurfaceview here because it should be quiet short.

Comment: In approach 2 I did this already. The while loop is needed by a algorithm to guarantee  to always have the same delta time. Look for example herer: http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/                   And its impossible that GC is the problem. If I dont allocate any memory there are still these lags all 2 seconds even if I disable loggin....

Comment: @Michael Buschmann: What if not call both of function, update() and render(), do you still have the lag?

Comment: I tried this already, too. Exactly the same Every few seconds I get delta times up to 80 MS.

Comment: @Michael Buschmann: Let's go over your code. see what I updated

Comment: Ok tanks I will try it.

Comment: I cannot find an official sample that use uses an constant FPS. Only one that refreshes if the surface is "dirty" but I need a sample with a constant fps.

Comment: @Michael Buschmann: in Android studio, you can search a sample at File -Import Sample

Comment: Yes but the only sample under opengl is a app that add effects to photos. No Continuous rendering.

Comment: Mh, but the NDK is a completly other thing or not ? Actually I dont wanted to use the NDK...

Comment: There is a opengl example in the NDK sample, no, It is almost same as you did like public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl){update();render()} in Java. Only one difference is render() update()  are c++ in NDK.

Comment: Ok I downloaded the NDK and tested a few of the samples. Exactly the same problems. And I tested it now on the HTC Desire 500, too but always the same.

Comment: @Michael Buschmann: I believe that is your PC problem. To make sure what, I would like you test without connecting to your PC.

Comment: I already tested this. The only thing that changed is the speed if I launch the app is smaller. But the lag problems are still the same.